# kinetic installation fails with 'Failed to detect successful installation of [qt5]' error

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, qt5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OS : OSX El Capitan , Version : 10.11.3

```
# rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y
executing command [brew install qt5]
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/science).
==> New Formulae
homebrew/science/fplll
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/qt5-5.6.1-1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring qt5-5.6.1-1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
We agreed to the Qt opensource license for you.
If this is unacceptable you should uninstall.

This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

Qt 5 conflicts Qt 4

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/qt5/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/qt5/include


.app bundles were installed.
Run `brew linkapps qt5` to symlink these to /Applications.
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.1-1: 7,494 files, 315.6M
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  homebrew: Failed to detect successful installation of [qt5]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242518/kinetic-installation-fails-with-%27failed-to-detect-successful-installation-of-%5Bqt5%5D%27-error/) by [Pillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/23727/pillai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-28**:
Please use the *Preformatted text* button next time for console copy/pastes. It's the one with the `101010` on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This happens because of the way homebrew deals with `qt5`. Notice how it says `This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.` Because `qt5` conflicts with `qt4`, anything that needs `qt5` has to be explicitly pointed at it, so as to not get confused with `qt4`. Since you know that your machine has `qt5` installed correctly, you can tell `rosdep` to just skip checking for `qt5` with:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y --skip-keys "libqt5-core libqt5-gui libqt5-opengl libqt5-opengl-dev libqt5-widgets qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev"
```

FYI I am working on installing ROS Kinetic onto my MBP running El Capitan. I'm going to try and list my progress on [this](https://gist.github.com/plusk01/bb92f6159c0818000865784abfd2a584) gist.

---

Originally posted by [plusk01](https://answers.ros.org/users/28128/plusk01/) with karma: 26 on 2016-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jeremie](https://answers.ros.org/users/29873/jeremie/) on 2017-03-30**:
Hi, I got similar issue... I tried with your line, but I got "given path 'src' does not exist"... which one is it ? I tried indigo_desktop_full_ws/src, but it also led to :

```
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  homebrew: Failed to detect successful installation of [qt]
```